# functools partial error : AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__module__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, functools

I've noticed this happens sometimes, usually I switch to lambda, but was wondering what I am doing that is causing it:

```
AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

Appears with:

```
def f(div, x):
    total = 0
    for row in x.iterrows():
        if row["DEPARTMENT DESC"] in div:
            total += row["TOTAL DIR COST"]
```

called using: `functools.partial(f,room)`

I would be very thankful for any help!

Comment: Could you post a minimal example that reproduces the error? It doesn't look like the problem is here

Comment: The problem is not with the partial call itself, but with what happens to the result afterwards. Presumably you're sending it through some code that expects a function object. Function and lambda objects have a `__module__` attribute, but partial objects don't. So when that code treats it like a regular function, it causes an error. It's hard to say more without seeing full code that reproduces the problem.